# Django: uploaded file encoding issues

Tags: python, django, encoding, upload

On the development platform upload works just fine, but when I deploy and test on the server upload fails with the following error

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /upload
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 25-30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I use

`django-ajax-uploader`,

`Django version: 1.3.1`,

`Python version: 2.6`

I believe it happens about files with `Roman`, `Russian`, `Chinese` filenames.

Also found similar discussion at

[Why do I get a ASCII encoding error with Unicode data in Python 2.4 but not in 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182384/why-do-i-get-a-ascii-encoding-error-with-unicode-data-in-python-2-4-but-not-in-2)

but about differences about Python versions.

I tried to set environment `$LANG` variable to `en_US.utf8` etc. but it didn't work.

Can anyone give me an advice or point a right way?

Thanks,

Sultan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [If you get a UnicodeEncodeError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) in the django docs.

Personally, I prefer to rename uploaded files to ASCII charset to avoid other problems as well. Here is a link to an [article with code](http://source.mihelac.org/2011/02/6/rename-uploaded-files-ascii-character-set-django/) that describes subclassing FileSystemStorage    .

Comment: thanks for advice, I end up with creation of transliteration  feature to provide valid filename for uploaded file